# What's bare minimum example of and Cake script Alias / Addin?

Tags: c#, cakebuild

I'm looking at Creating my own addin for Cake to extend the DSL, documentation's a bit lacking.

What's the bare minimum needed for creating an Cake addin script alias?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An addin is just an regular .NET Assembly packaged as an NuGet package, as a matter of fact in general you can reference almost any .NET assembly.

What an alias adds beyond regular assembly:

- Adds methods to the Cake DSL making it available globally in Cake scripts
- Namespace imports (can make types available without need of using statement)
- Access to Cake Core classes/features

A minimal alias implementation would be an extension method that extends [Cake.Core.ICakeContext](http://cakebuild.net/api/cake.core/f005e67e) which has the [Cake.Core.Annotations.CakeAlias](http://cakebuild.net/api/cake.core.annotations/cc91ec32) attribute.

So a minimal implementation would be, create an .NET assembly, add a reference to the [Cake.Core](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Cake.Core/) nuget package and add a class like below:

```cs
public static class HelloWorldAliases
{
        [CakeMethodAlias]
        public static void HelloWorld(this ICakeContext context)
        {
             context.Log.Information("Hello {0}", "World");
        }
}
```

To test your alias you can load your assembly via the [#reference](http://cakebuild.net/docs/fundamentals/preprocessor-directives) directive or if you packaged it via the [#addin](http://cakebuild.net/docs/fundamentals/preprocessor-directives) directive.
You can then call your alias in a script using `HelloWorld()` the ICakeContext can be omitted as it's automatically provided by the Cake core engine.

Example "HelloWorld" Cake script:

```cs
#reference "HelloWorld.dll"
HelloWorld();
```

If you have any namespaces you want to automatically import for the user, then you do that using the [CakeNamespaceImport](http://cakebuild.net/api/cake.core.annotations/0a570436) attribute to your extension method, example:

```cs
public static class HelloWorldAliases
{
        [CakeMethodAlias]
        [CakeNamespaceImport("MyNameSpace.Common")]
        public static void HelloWorld(this ICakeContext context)
        {
             context.Log.Information("Hello {0}", "World");
        }
}
```

Any type in `MyNameSpace.Common` will now be made available without the need to add a `using MyNameSpace.Common` to the script.

Once you’ve packaged your addin and published to nuget, then you can reference it by package id using the [#addin](http://cakebuild.net/docs/fundamentals/preprocessor-directives) directive, example:

```cs
#addin "HelloWorld"
HelloWorld();
```